# dompdf generating damaged pdfs in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I am using dompdf for generating pdf in codeigniter application, 
When I am opening pdf its giving error

[image]"

I checked all stackoverflow stuffs for this,

- [Corrupt PDF on the fly attached to email via dompdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875865/corrupt-pdf-on-the-fly-attached-to-email-via-dompdf)
- [cannot open pdf file generated using dompdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676160/cannot-open-pdf-file-generated-using-dompdf)
- [Generating a PDF using CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035112/generating-a-pdf-using-codeigniter)

and more,but no luck,
my code is :

```
$html = file_get_contents(base_url() . "sampleHTMLfilepath");
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
if (is_null($this->_dompdf)) {
    $this->_dompdf = new DOMPDF();
}
$this->_dompdf->load_html($html);
$this->_dompdf->render();
$this->_dompdf->stream('test.pdf);
```

sample html is simple file with p tag

```
<p>Hello </p>
```

Please help me,
Thanks

Comment: your code should not even run because of the missing `'` in the last line.

Comment: Often a corrupt PDF is caused by the insertion of PHP errors/notices into the PDF source. This can happen if you have output buffering enabled. Try opening the PDF in a text editor, if this is the cause you'll likely see the PHP errors before the PDF source.

Comment: @BrianS 's comment helped me diagnose the same issue for my code. Thanks for the pointer. If a corrupt file is indeed getting downloaded, open it up using a text editor and look for PHP errors and save yourself a lot of headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no one should be down voting this question. anyway try something like this in your controller method, convert for your use.

```
// get some content
$data['order'] = $this->printmodel->getOrder();

// Load a view like you would normally do
$this->load->view('orderprint', $data);

// before going any further, 
// make sure the content is showing on the view with no errors
// when you call the method

// all good? ok now add this part 

// Get the output html  
$html = $this->output->get_output();

// Load library
$this->load->library('dompdf_gen');

// Create pdf name based on date, hour, seconds
$pdfname = date("FjYgias");

// Convert to PDF
// (this is for streaming the pdf directly)
$this->dompdf->load_html($html);
$this->dompdf->render();
$this->dompdf->stream($pdfname);
```

and this is a much more complicated example then what you are trying to do - you don't have to call a model, etc - you can just call the view,

```
$this->load->view('somethingcooltoprint');
```

confirm its working and then do the rest of the code like above.